# React Native: Reducer Becomes Undefined After Initial Fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I am encountering a problem with my Redux setup in React Native where I have two reducers: one for authentication and another for menu. While the auth reducer persists data across the entire app without any issues, the menu reducer seems to have a problem. After the `getMenu()` action is called, the menu state initially populates data correctly, but then immediately becomes undefined. I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. I want to be able to persist the menu data throughout the entire application.

Code:

```
//store.js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
} from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import authReducer from "./auth/authReducer";
import menuReducer from "./menu/menuReducer";

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  keyPrefix: "redux-",
  whitelist: [],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  menu: menuReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

```
//menuReducer.js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  menu: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const menuSlice = createSlice({
  name: "menu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
     setLoading: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = action.payload;
    },
    setError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    },
    setMenu: (state, action) => {
      state.menu = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    },
    clearMenu: (state) => {
      state.menu = null;
    },
    clearError: (state) => {
      state.error = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase("menu/getMenu/pending", (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase("menu/getMenu/fulfilled", (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.menu = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase("menu/getMenu/rejected", (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
export const { setLoading, setError, setMenu, clearMenu, clearError } =
  menuSlice.actions;
export default menuSlice.reducer;
```

Here is how i update the menu state with data:

```
//menuAction.js
export const getMenu = createAsyncThunk(
  "menu/getMenu",
  async ({ storeNumber, token }, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const menu = await GetMenuApi(storeNumber, token);
      dispatch(setMenu(menu));
      dispatch(clearError());
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(setError(error));
    }
  }
);
```

```
//App.js
export default function App(){
  const { menu } = useSelector((state) => state.menu);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const storeNumber = 1;
  const token = 'abc'

  console.log(menu) //logs correct data then immediately logs undefined

  const getMenuFunc= () => {
    dispatch(getMenu({ storeNumber, token }));
  };

  return(
   <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Button onPress={getMenuFunc} title="get menu"/>
   </View>
  );
}
```

After invoking the `getMenuFunc()` function, the `console.log(menu)` correctly logs the menu data the first time. However, upon subsequent invocations of `getMenuFunc()`, the `menu` variable becomes `undefined`. Interestingly, upon app reload via Expo and subsequent invocation of `getMenuFunc()`, the data is retrieved again, only to become `undefined` once more.

Comment: Based on your description it's unclear if you are using only a single Redux store, or two stores. By "store" do you mean the two reducers, "auth" and "menu"? What initial fetch are you referring to? This doesn't appear to be a complete [mcve]. Can you [edit] to clarify the problem and include all relevant code you are working with?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your feedback. I've revised my question to provide more clarity. I am indeed using two separate Redux stores: one for authentication and another for menu. The initial fetch refers to fetching menu data from an API upon app initialization. I have made some edits on the question and added relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Your `getMenu` action isn't returning any payload value, so the `setMenu` action is dispatched and the state is updated with the `menu` value, only to be wiped out by the `getMenu.fulfilled` action that has an undefined payload value.

```js
export const getMenu = createAsyncThunk(
  "menu/getMenu",
  async ({ storeNumber, token }, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const menu = await GetMenuApi(storeNumber, token);
      dispatch(setMenu(menu)); // (1) <-- has menu payload
      dispatch(clearError());
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
      // (2) <-- missing return implicitly returns undefined payload
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(setError(error));
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const menuSlice = createSlice({
  name: "menu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
     setLoading: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = action.payload;
    },
    setError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    },
    setMenu: (state, action) => {
      state.menu = action.payload; // <-- (1) menu payload 
      state.loading = false;
    },
    clearMenu: (state) => {
      state.menu = null;
    },
    clearError: (state) => {
      state.error = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase("menu/getMenu/pending", (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase("menu/getMenu/fulfilled", (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.menu = action.payload; // (2) <-- undefined payload 
      })
      .addCase("menu/getMenu/rejected", (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```

You are making more work for yourself though. Just use the thunk actions directly and ensure you properly return values from your `getMenu` action.

## Solution

Update `getMenu` to correctly return the menu as a resolved/fulfilled payload. Do the same thing for errors.

Example:

```js
export const getMenu = createAsyncThunk(
  "menu/getMenu",
  ({ storeNumber, token }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      return GetMenuApi(storeNumber, token); // <-- return menu payload
    } catch (error) {
      rejectWithValue(error); // <-- return rejection value
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const menuSlice = createSlice({
  name: "menu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getMenu.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getMenu.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.menu = action.payload; // <-- menu payload 
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(getMenu.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload; // <-- menu fetch error
      });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you wrapped your root component with PersistGate? if not then you need to wrap it because it delays the rendering of your app's UI until your persisted state has been retrieved and saved to redux. otherwise, your app will load before the state is saved to the redux store hence you will get undefined when you try to access the state because it does not exist on the store.

Please check the link below for more [https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20react%2C%20wrap%20your%20root%20component%20with%20PersistGate.%20This%20delays%20the%20rendering%20of%20your%20app%27s%20UI%20until%20your%20persisted%20state%20has%20been%20retrieved%20and%20saved%20to%20redux.%20NOTE%20the%20PersistGate%20loading%20prop%20can%20be%20null%2C%20or](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20react%2C%20wrap%20your%20root%20component%20with%20PersistGate.%20This%20delays%20the%20rendering%20of%20your%20app%27s%20UI%20until%20your%20persisted%20state%20has%20been%20retrieved%20and%20saved%20to%20redux.%20NOTE%20the%20PersistGate%20loading%20prop%20can%20be%20null%2C%20or)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that there is a confusion of RTK usage :)

In your slice, under the `reducers` key, you're re-inventing the wheel of the `extraReducer` + `createAsyncThunk`

**1st solution (not the best IMO)** : don't use `createAsyncThunk`

You can write your thunk like that.
If you choose this solution, you can also remove `extraReducers`.
The issue is that action dispatched by createAsyncThunk are in conflict with the one you defined

```js
export const getMenu = async ({ storeNumber, token }) => ({ dispatch }) => {
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const menu = await GetMenuApi(storeNumber, token);
      dispatch(setMenu(menu));
      dispatch(clearError());
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(setError(error));
    }
  };
```

**2nd solution** : RTK for the win

If you check the doc of [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#promise-lifecycle-actions), you'll see that 3 action are generated => the one that you defined under `extraReducers` key. But more important, `menu/getMenu/pending` is dispatched directly when the thunk is dispatched and `menu/getMenu/fulfilled` when there was no error.

With that in mind, you have a conflict

So we'll have the following code

```js
// Thunk is now super simple => put as much logic as possible in reducers ;)
// https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers
export const getMenu = createAsyncThunk(
  "menu/getMenu",
  async ({ storeNumber, token }, { dispatch }) => {
      return await GetMenuApi(storeNumber, token);
  }
);
```

```js
const menuSlice = createSlice({
  name: "menu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearMenu: (state) => {
      state.menu = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // Tip : instead of string, you can pass the thunk.(pending|fulfilled|error)
    // in order to avoid typo
    builder
      .addCase(getMenu.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getMenu.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        // The `payload` is what was returned form the thunk
        state.menu = action.payload;
        
        // This was previously done by the `clearError` action
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(getMenu.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        // If you don't use `rejectWithValue`, error will be under `error` key
        state.error = action.error;
      });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Async thunks should be used for handling asynchronous logic such as making API calls. Dispatching actions should be handled in the "extrareducers"  section of the slice where you define how your state should respond to different actions.

```
 //Define the async thunk to fetch menuData
export const getMenu = createAsyncThunk(
  'menu/getMenu',
      async ((storeNumber, token), { dispatch }) => {
        // Async logic, API call
        try {
         const menu = await GetMenuApi(storeNumber, token);
          return menu; // Return data to be used in the reducer
        } catch (error) {
          throw error; // Re-throw the error to handle it in the rejected action
        }
      }
    );

//App.js
    const menuSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'menu',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Add any synchronous actions here
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getMenu.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
        state.error = null; // Clear any existing error
      })
      .addCase(getMenu.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.menu = action.payload; // Update the state with the fetched data
      })
      .addCase(getMenu.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.error.message; // Update the error state with the error message
      });
  },
});
```

---